# $a\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ Find a and b

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> $$a\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
> Find a and b

I've found the answers to this to be $\frac{1}{13}$ and $\frac{4}{13}$ through google but just wondering, how would I go about working this through and finding the answer myself?

Comment: Express it as a system of two equations, two unknowns.  Then solve it.

Comment: I changed `{matrix}` to `{pmatrix}`. If you want [ ], you can edit it to `{bmatrix}`. As to your question, each entry of the matrices are independent of the other.

Comment: You have 2 linear simultaneous equations: $a+3b = 1$ and $4a-b=0$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the two matrices as shown and you will have following equations:

1. $$a+3b=1$$
2. $$4a-b=0$$
   From (2), we have: $$b=4a$$
   Putting in (1), we get: $$a+3(4a)=1$$
   this implies, $$13a=1$$
   So $$a=\frac{1}{13} $$ and $$b=\frac{4}{13}$$

Answer (score 1):

You would set up two equations in the unknowns $a,b$, by using the fact that vectors are equal if and only if their components are equal. Thus, you get
$$a+3b=1,\quad\hbox{and}\quad 4a-b=0$$
which I am pretty sure you can solve.